# Bluetooth performance

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, macbook-pro

I'm getting very bad Bluetooth results.
Especialy with audio, but not only.
Basically, everything "works" but overall experience is really bad.

laptop: Ubuntu 17.10 artful on macbookpro (single boot, uefi).
headset: Apple airpods
keyboard: magickeyboard2
trackpad: magictrackpad2
mouse: magicmouse2
gamepad: PS4 controller

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 1
Product Name: MacBookPro12,1

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10

$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 11.0-89-g922f0

$ dpkg -l|grep bluez
ii  bluez    5.47-1

$ dpkg -l |grep magictrackpad
ii  hid-magictrackpad2-dkms    
(https://github.com/ponyfleisch/hid-magictrackpad2)

$ uname -a
Linux box 4.14.5-041405-lowlatency #201712101332 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 10 13:35:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've updated everything I could think of.
Yes the results are like this:

- audio: lots of skips, long pauses, crackling noises, loss of signal if I get farther than few centimeters from laptop (around 30cm)
- mouse and keyboard: slow to reaction, movement is choppy
- gamepad: slow to reaction, keeps acting like if buttons or dpad are pressed while they are not, miss some events..

Keyboard and mouse/trackpad are the one working best. It's possible to use them. Experience isn't great though.
Gamepad: it defeat the point of being wireless. I must be so close to the laptop I'd better use a wired gamepad instead.
Audio is the absolute worst. While technically: 'sound do get transmitted to my headset' in practice it is useless. And as with gamepad I must stay very close to the laptop otherwise signal is lost.

By the way, as a comparison point: the same headset works fantastic (!) with my Android phone. (and of course with macOS too).
I suspect the rest of the equipment would work nicely too on Android, but as I've only used the airpods with my phone I can't comment on the other elements. Yet compared to Linux it's like night and day.

Would anyone be able to suggest something? Is there anything that could be done?